# Toolbar doubles option in menu in more button

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a `Toolbar` in my `Activity`, then i inflate a menu in my fragment, the issue is that it adds the same options even in `more` button, which shouldn't even exist and the function on layoutManager and adapterTables are not even executed (but the icon is changed)

Activity:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:navigationIconTint="#737373"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_white"
        app:title="Tavolo"
        app:subtitle="Seleziona tavolo"
        app:subtitleTextColor="#737373"
        app:titleTextColor="#737373" />


</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/tableMap"
        android:title="@string/mappa_tavoli"
        android:contentDescription="@string/mappa_tavoli"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_table_restaurant_24"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/changeLayout"
        android:title="@string/modifica_layout"
        android:contentDescription="@string/modifica_layout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_grid_view"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Fragment:

```
public class TablesFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    private Listener mListener;

    GridLayoutManager layoutManager;
    AdapterTables adapterTables;

    public void setListener(@Nullable Listener mListener) {
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }

    public interface Listener {
        void onClickTable(String table);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tables, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        initUI(view);
    }

    private void initUI(View view) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewTables);
        layoutManager = (GridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

        ArrayList<Tables> listTables = new ArrayList<>();
        listTables.add(new Tables("1", "F", "", "50m", ""));
        listTables.add(new Tables("2", "O", "", "30m", "2,50"));
        listTables.add(new Tables("3", "F", "", "30m", ""));
        listTables.add(new Tables("4", "F", "Veranda", "50m", ""));
        listTables.add(new Tables("5", "O", "", "", "5,00"));
        listTables.add(new Tables("6", "F", "", "50m", ""));
        listTables.add(new Tables("7", "O", "", "30m", "9,00"));
        adapterTables = new AdapterTables(layoutManager, listTables);
        adapterTables.setListener(idTable -> mListener.onClickTable(listTables.get(idTable).getId()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterTables);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.table, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.changeLayout) {
            if (layoutManager.getSpanCount() == 1) {
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_format_list_bulleted);
                layoutManager.setSpanCount(4);
            } else {
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_grid_view);
                layoutManager.setSpanCount(1);
            }
            adapterTables.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, adapterTables.getItemCount());
            return true;
        }else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.tableMap) {
            getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container_view, TablesMapFragment.class, null)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is how the toolbar is on the device:

[image]

EDIT:

When i change the fragment the menu returns to work as it have to:

[image]

As you can see the menu starts to work only after i pressed the table option which do a fragment replace, then by pressing to list option it replace the fragment to the previous and the menù is set correctly, but not at the first start..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that at the activity start i was calling:

```
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setReorderingAllowed(true)
            .add(R.id.fragment_container_view, TablesFragment.class, null)
            .commit();
```

By changing the `.add` to `.replace` it started to work as expected.